# Order multiple entities by date with query-builder (Symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder

I was wondering if I could possibly order multiple entities by their date of creation with the query builder in Symfony.

This is my query:

```
public function findContributions(Association $association)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('d, ms, m')
            ->addSelect('greatest(ms.createdAt, d.createdAt) AS date')
            ->from(Membership::class, 'ms')
            ->from(Donation::class, 'd')
            ->leftJoin('ms.member', 'm')
            ->Where('m.association = a.id')
            ->andWhere('d.association = a.id')
            ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
```

[My results so far :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShOmh.png)

I would like to order by the column created_at located in both of my entities (membership and donation).

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thank you !

Comment: if doctrine understands greatest (eg. by using https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/Greatest.php ) then it should work but just add it to the select() itself like `->select('d, ms, m, greatest(ms.createdAt, d.createdAt) as date')`

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply !
I've tried it but the result is still the same, I might have to do it programmatically
Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
 public function addOrderBy($sort, $order = null); // Default $order = 'ASC'
```

Doing something like

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('d, ms, m')
            ->addSelect('greatest(ms.createdAt, d.createdAt) AS date')
            ->from(Membership::class, 'ms')
            ->from(Donation::class, 'd')
            ->leftJoin('ms.member', 'm')
            ->Where('m.association = a.id')
            ->andWhere('d.association = a.id')
            ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC')
            ->addOrderBy('d.date', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

(taken from the doctrine documentation : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods)

Comment: Hey,
I already tried to use addOrderBy and unfortunately, it didn't affect the results.
Thank you for your reply, anyway !

Comment: of course not - this sorts first by m.date then by d.date

Comment: MySQL doesn't let you sort on two fields at the same time, I don't think Doctrine has a method to do it. I think you'll have to do it programmatically